# Why does the child component have more props than the parent?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a parent component that I want to be tabs for multiple children. For some reason, my child component has more props data than the parent.

Parent component

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TerritoryTabs extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('this is the parent props (tabs)')
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (

    {this.props.children}

    );
  }

}

export default connect(null, null)(TerritoryTabs);
```

Child component

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import { getTerritoryGeographies } from '../actions/index';

import TerritoryTabs from './territory-tabs';

class TerritoryGeographyList extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('this is child props (TerritoryGeographyList)');
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getTerritoryGeographies(this.props.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <TerritoryTabs>

          <div>This list goes here</div>

    </TerritoryTabs>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { territoryGeographies: state.territoryGeographies.all
        };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getTerritoryGeographies })(TerritoryGeographyList);
```

Here is what the console prints.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, and you don't show the actual JSX (or whatever) that's showing this. If you pass it more props, it'll have more props, plus you map a prop.

Comment: @DaveNewton but my child has more prop data. So I need to pass props form the child to the parent? Doesn't that go against react convention?

Comment: Your "child" component (TerritoryGeographyList) is wrapping your "parent" component (TerritoryTabs). Interesting, why did you call them that way? The wrap one should be called "parent".

Comment: ^^ yes `TerritoryGeographyList` is the parent.  `TerritoryTabs` is the child.  You are just slightly mixed up.

Comment: @TrungDQ Because in my react route `<Route path="territory/:id/geography/list" component={TerritoryGeographyList} />` the list component is what I want to call when I reach that url.

Comment: So you are saying that `TerritoryTabs` the child? I'm seeing you are console log `this is the parent props (tabs)` inside `TerritoryTabs`. Check your question.

Comment: @Brandon, so my parent (TerritoryGeographyList), is being wrapped by my child (TerritoryTabs) ? That seems really backwards. I would think the Tab would be the parent since the list content is a child.

Comment: no.  `TerritoryGeographyList` is the parent and it _renders_ its child `TerritoryTabs`.

Comment: @Brandon, so guess my question needs to be, how to pass the props to a child component?

Comment: yes probably.  There's lots of questions for that already, but really just `<TerritoryTabs route={this.props.route} somethingElse={42}>` is the basic idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrap component should be called "parent". Example:

```
<Parent>
    <Child />
</Parent>
```

So, in your case, fix this line:

```
class TerritoryTabs extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('this is the child props (tabs)') // <-- Fix this line, it should be the "child"
    console.log(this.props);
  }
```

and this line:

```
class TerritoryGeographyList extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('this is parent props (TerritoryGeographyList)'); // <-- fix this line, it should be "parent"
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.getTerritoryGeographies(this.props.params.id);
  }
```

Comment: @TylerZika: Important to remember: the Parent is the one that renders the child in its render method.  Thus the parent is able to pass props to the child by adding attributes to the child when rendering (e.g. `<Child prop1={1} prop2={this.props.foo} >`)